# The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am facing a weird error. The background was that I have installed a Facebook app prior to installing my own app. When I started my app and it asked to login to Facebook with `publish_stream` permission, it worked properly. I was able to post into Facebook fan pages on behalf of users.

But, I took a device which already has Facebook installed and a user logged in, and it throws an error.

Please what im doing wrong ?

Im using Android sdk 3.0

Comment: Hey I am having same issue with Facebook SDK 3.5, did u find any solution ?